# Problem During Raspberry Pi Event Detection

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'd like to calculate RPM of the rotating disk (with aluminium foil on it) using the circular array of 10 holes in it and the proximity sensor.

[image: LOOK_AT_THE_PHOTO]

Unfortunately, instead of counting ONLY events (changes from the aluminium foil to the holes) I have lots of unwanted numbers.

I've tried to figure out what's going on but without any positive result. For example, if I fix (without any visible motion of the disk) the aluminium foil opposite to the proximity switch, detect_motion() function will be called constantly every 0.003-0.004 s. Bounce time doesn't work well.

```
from __future__ import division
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import Adafruit_PCA9685
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

pwm = Adafruit_PCA9685.PCA9685()

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

pwm.set_pwm_freq(60)

pwm.set_pwm(0, 0, 4095)
pwm.set_pwm(1, 0, 1000)

time_motion = [0]
delta_time = [0]

row = 0

def detect_motion(ev=None):

    global row

    row += 1    

    time_motion.append(time.time())
    a = time_motion[-1] - time_motion[-2]
    print(a)

    worksheet.write(row, 0, a)
    workbook.close()

    delta_time.append(a)

    del time_motion[-2]
    del delta_time[-2]

GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.add_event_detect(17, GPIO.FALLING, callback=detect_motion, bouncetime=10)
```

The time intervals between changing events (foil to hole) are needed. Using them I will be able to calculate RPM of the disk.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can help you with this, but I'd be interested to know if (a) if you see activity if the proximity sensor is disconnected, and (b) What happens when you take the disc away (I think you are implying that the event doesn't fire) , and (c) what is the make and model of the sensor.

Comment: There's also a Stack Exchange group just for Raspberry Pi, which may be a better forum for this question. My searching for GPIO information often end up there https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: (a) no; (b) nothing; (c) inductive proximity switch LJ12A3-4-Z/BX three-wire NPN normally open. I've connected the switch to MCP3008 (resolution - 1024 bits) in order to analyze the analogue signal. It fluctuates from 65 to 210 bits very rapidly when the switch is opposite to the foil. However, with the hole in front of it the signal is constant - 1023 bits. Is there a way to tune the sensitivity of the event_detect? For instance, make it unresponsive to these fluctuations?

Comment: Full scale on the MCP3008 is 3.3V which I presume is 1023+ (maybe +++?). It looks like the voltage is pretty small when opposite the foil if maximum is 210, so about .67V. Maybe it is spiking higher than what you've seen. I would expect .67V to read as 0 on the Pi, as the threshold is supposed to be between .8 and 2.0V. The datasheet for the sensor is somewhat short on detail, so can you examine the output with an oscilloscope, and/or maybe use a voltage divider on the output to get the ADC to read just below 1023. What is the supply voltage on the sensor?

Comment: Also the 300ma sensor output current seems like a lot. Going into a high impedance GPIO might be an issue - again an argument for a voltage divider or at least a resistor to act as a sink for the current (again, I don't claim to be an expert on this).

Comment: One more question. The spec sheet says max 4mm from the metal. What is the distance? It looks more than that but it could be just the picture. It would be interesting to see what the effect of distance is on the voltage.

Comment: I've tried 5 and 15 V. There is no difference. The switch is located 1-2 mm from the foil. I've replaced the inductive switch to an optical one and it works well... it looks like something is wrong with the inductive switch

Comment: Too bad. I guess I'll never know what really was wrong. I'm glad it worked with with the optical sensor.

Comment: Anyway, thank you very much for your support!